# HDF5 dataspace interface - What does it do and what is it's real world application

Tags: r, hdf5, hdf, rhdf5

I am currently building some applications which make use of HDF5 files. My language of choice is `R`.

I have already taken a look at the hdfgroup website with regards to [dataspace](https://support.hdfgroup.org/HDF5/doc/H5.user/Dataspaces.html) and I think I understand the concept. But I am very much unable to understand it's real world use.

Can someone please, tell me what is the dataspace interface supposed to be used for?

Currently, I think if I load a matrix of size `1.5M x 1.5M` I may be able to store dataspace coordinates and then retrieve that piece of data much faster. Is this correct?

It would be great if you can also provide an example.

Comment: Does not seem to be a specific question (lack of clarity was my close vote reason), but if it is an implicit request that we look up a real-world example of this HDF5 data structure in the programming language R, then it would also be off-topic and cloosed for that reason.

Comment: @42- there is already a package named rhdf5 which handles hdf5 files for R. It exposes the HDF5 dataspace interface. My question relates to how the dataspace interface is useful and the question asks for an example of that usefulness.